# Java: how to require subclasses to call super() when super's argument is a vararg

Tags: java

I have an abstract class which has a constructor that takes varargs. The Java compiler doesn't seem to require that child classes call super() even though every constructor takes arguments.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public Parent(String... varargs) {

    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    // I would like this to be a compile error. Child should always call super().
}
```

How can I write `Parent` so that children must call `super()`?

Comment: That's because child is abstract

Comment: Any class that extends child must have a constructor that calls the super()

Comment: The abstract keyword on Child was a typo -- the code compiles fine without it.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of a varargs method is to allow the programmer to write each argument individually, so it's possible to prepend a required argument of the same type to make sure at least one is passed in. For callers that have a list or array, an alternate constructor can accept `Iterable`.

```
public abstract class Parent2 {
    public Parent2(String firstArg, String... varargs) {

    }

    public Parent2(Iterable<? extends String> args) {

    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent2 {
    public Child2() {
        super("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your question **as written**.  What you have actually done is to change superclass constructor's signature from "zero or more args" to "one or more args".

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), the number of parameters passed to a method/constructor accepting a `varargs` parameter, can be *none*, making the constructor act as a default parameter less constructor too.

> To use varargs, you follow the type of the last parameter by an
>   ellipsis (three dots, ...), then a space, and the parameter name. The
>   method can then be called with any number of that parameter, **including
>   none.**

So you could change it to an array,

```
abstract class Parent {
    public Parent(String[] varargs) {

    }
}
```

your child constructor would be forced to call this constructor explicitly.